# Need to convert unbalanced to differential input OPAMP

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential, conversion, balanced, unbalanced

I have the following filter after the DAC chip (currently with unbalanced outputs) working very well, but I need now to change the DAC chip. The new source has differential outputs.

Is there a simple way to convert the filter (maintaining identical performances)  using differential inputs, instead of unbalanced like now?

Is there any simple formula for the components? (Output should remain RCA unbalanced). Usually differencial opamp circuitry should have mirroring components on both inputs, correct?

[image]

I doesn't matter to still use two opamps or add an extra one.

Comment: Components values in the schematic are dummy as I cannot reproduce true ones for copyright reason, but please use these one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Diff Amp uses RC feedback on Vin+ to gnd . With low tolerances like 0.1% for 60dB CMRR then use both R diff inputs.

### Other

The filter is suboptimal cascaded as a 1+ 3rd order filter =4th order LPF and is better designed with specs for group delay, Q BW, etc., to optimize bandpass range and bandstop rejection,  when both Op Amp filters are integrated.

See my other related answers using TI filter design tool.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I need to know the schematic by using the same components (same number of zeros and order) . Can you please post a draft?

Comment: I could but you might need to sign an NDA (j/k)

Comment: I just realized I cannot do that on an iPad. So imagine same Feedback parts shunted to Vin+ to gnd. Then open ground and use differential input R’s

Comment: Disregard 2nd diff output sht cct.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't reply to my initial question: need exactly the same components values and slopes which I'm using in my attached circuit.

Comment: SORRY but you have to learn. I showed you how with the software and learn to give specs